# Ruby- web api with rest client gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, rest-client

I'm new in Ruby (and in developing too), and I would like to get the response from another url (my url) in the get method.

I'm using rest-client gem.

I have tried this code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  require 'rest-client'
  def index
    RestClient::Request.execute(method: :get, url: 'https://my-url')
  end
end
```

But when I open http://localhost:3000/users, I get a blank page. Can anyone help me understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should render the response text:

```
require 'rest-client'

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render text: RestClient::Request.execute( method: :get, url: 'https://my-url').to_str, layout: nil
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it works!

Comment: @Joel You are welcome! Accept my answer then (click the V-shaped mark near it) :) And if you like it, you might consider upvoting it too :)